# Why vertical-align CSS property not working and does not put span in middle height of its parent?

Tags: html, css

I have hard time understanding `vertical-align` property for some time now, and I haven't successfully managed to apply that, so I decided to write here.

Having simple markup

```
<div class="parent">
  <span class="text">Some text centered here
</div>
```

and

```
.parent{
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  .text{
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color:green;
  }
}
```

results in

[image]

why span is not centered in parent container? To what exactly this property applies to?

Code pen for you:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wXYoBO

Please be aware that **I am not asking here how to center element in div**, but why this particular css property does not work as common sense would suggest me to.

Here, vertical-align starts to take affect
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QxZpYP

Comment: vertical-align should be applied to an element in order to vertical align it based on the text ... actually you have nothing to align, if you have 2 spans, then you can align one of them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css)

Comment: check this ; https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/ until I find the good duplicate question ;)

Comment: *The vertical-align property in CSS controls how **elements set next to each other** on a line are lined up* Wow that is crucial part there. It would explain a lot....

Comment: I added a simplified answer so you can have a clear idea but for in deep explanation better refer to the full specification ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `vertical-align: middle` it needs to be combined with `display: table-cell` and applied **for parent** and I would not recommend this solution, however below is your code, fixed, and some other solutions.

### Solution 1

```css
.parent{
  height:100px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: red
}

.text{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="text">Some text centered here</span>
</div>
```

### Solution 2

Using defined `line-height` for `.parent` and `vertical-align` for child. In this solution child aligns itself vertically relative to `line-height`, which is stretched -- it has 100px.

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.text {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="text">Some text centered here</span>
</div>
```

### Solution 3

I would recommend using `display: flex`, because use of `display: table-cell` outside of tables is not a good practice, at all.`align-items: center` aligns content vertically, while `justify-content: center` aligns content horizontally.

```css
.parent{
  height:100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color:red
}

.text{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="text">Some text centered here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thansk Andrzej for workaround, but do you know what actually causes that to not work?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align says it it applies to table cells as well as to inline elements. So what do I miss here?

Comment: `vertical-align: middle` must be applied to element with `display: table-cell`. Your `.parent` doesn't have `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` is applied to child, `.text`, instead of parent, `.parent`.

Comment: vertical-align don't only work with table-cell ...read the doc and you will see it work perfectly with span and inline element if we do it correctly

Comment: Using predefined `line-height`? It does, but I think it's a dirty way of doing things. I added it to my answer anyway, thanks.

Comment: Quiting: *The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of **an inline** or table-cell box.* So it should work for inline lements, but for some reasons it don't - I want to know that reasons:)

Comment: See my **Solution 2**. It works on inline elements when you define `line-height` on which it has to align.

Comment: no, line-height has nothing to do with vertical-align too ... vertical-aling work with **adjacent** elements @Antoniossss check the link I shared, it doesn't work on an element alone

Comment: `vertical-align` works with `line-height` and it works with adjacent elements, but only when there are any. Creating dummy element is not possible here, as it requires giving `font-size` to this dummy element, and we can't give font size equal to parent element's height. I would create a chat room if I could.

Answer (score 2):

Vertical align doesn't work on divs, a common workaround is to use **display: table-cell** in the container:

```
.parent{
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  .text{
    background-color:green;
  }
}
```

Or, using **CSS3 Flexbox**, you can use this:

```
.parent{
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  display : flex;
  align-items : center;
  .text{
    background-color:green;
  }
}
```

Comment: So it will work on inline element inside inline element ? like span in span?

Comment: Yes, it should work, span is an inline element by default, but you are changing the display property to table-cell or flex

Comment: I don't! That is something everyone suggest me to do

Comment: I believe my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51056965/why-vertical-align-css-property-not-working-and-does-not-put-span-in-middle-heig/51057069#51057069) is pretty straightforward. You are using `vertical-align: middle` in a wrong way. It needs to be applied to `.parent` with `display: table-cell` at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If we check [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) we will read this:

> The vertical-align property can be used in two contexts:
>
> To vertically align an **inline element's box** inside **its containing line**
>   **box**. For example, it could be used to vertically position an `<img>` in
>   a line of text:

But what is a **line box**?

You can refer to this part of the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting) to get better idea about line boxes. It may be complex at the start but to make it easy [the height of the line box](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height) is defined by the inline element.

In your case, you have only **one** inline element that define the line box and its height is equal to the height of the line box thus there is nothing to align as all the alignment will be equivalent.

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
span {
 background:pink;
 /*All these values will define the line box*/
 line-height:25px;
 font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<span>text</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
<span style="vertical-align:middle;">text</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
<span style="vertical-align:top;">text</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
<span style="vertical-align:bottom;">text</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
<span style="vertical-align:text-top;">text</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
<span style="vertical-align:text-bottom;">text</span>
</div>
```

Now, suppose you have two inlines elements with different properties (`font-size`, `line-height`, `font-family`, etc). In this case, the line box will be calulcated considering both elements like described in the specification and `vertical-align` will have an effect in this case because:

> When **the height of a box B** is less **than the height of the line box**
>   containing it, the vertical alignment of B within the line box is
>   determined by the 'vertical-align' property.

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
span {
 background:pink;
}
span:last-child {
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<span>text</span><span>big text</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
<span style="vertical-align:middle;">text</span><span >big text</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
<span style="vertical-align:top;">text</span><span>big text</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
<span style="vertical-align:bottom;">text</span><span >big text</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
<span style="vertical-align:text-top;">text</span><span >big text</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
<span style="vertical-align:text-bottom;">text</span><span >big text</span>
</div>
```

As you can see the line box is defined by the bigger text and now you can align the small text with within it.

*This is a very simplified explanation using simple wording, refer to the specification for a more accurate and complete explanation.*

Comment: If you have luck, maybe BoltClock or Alohaci will be around to correct me and give you better explanation ;)

Answer (score 0):

As it states [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) you cannot use `vertical-align` in block-level elements. Your code isn't working because div is such a block-level element. In order for your code to work you must use some other kind of element.

Damian Peralta has done this by using `table-cell` on your parent. The other problem is that you applied `vertical-align` to the child, which is by default just as high and wide as it needs to be. So effectively your code is working, it centers the contents of your span (the text), you just dont't see it because the span is exactly as high as the text itself.

So you have two options:

1) Use some non block-element as parent and apply `vertical-align` to the parent

```
.parent{
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  vertical-align:middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
.text{
  background-color:green;
}
```

2)  Or make the text element higher:

```
.parent{
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
.text{
  background-color:green;
  // You need to use line-height here because the height of inline elements cannot be changed
  line-height: 100px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```css
.parent{
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
  display:table;
}
.text{
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color:green;
  display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="text">Some text centered here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: while this code may answer the question, adding explanation on why and how it solves it would improve the quality of the answer

Comment: @ᴄʀᴏᴢᴇᴛ okay sure.

Answer (score -2):

There are many ways to align element on center vertically and/or horizontally. I find this [guidelines](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)  very useful.

My favourite is to use flexbox technique since most of the time I don't want to fix the height and width.